# CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF placeholders start or end with

Tags: django, settings, placeholder, django-cms

Is there any way to set all placeholders that starts with 'foo' or end with 'bar' in CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF

example:

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'foo_*': {
        'name': "Starts with",
        'default_plugins': [
            {
                'plugin_type': 'TextPlugin',
                'values': {
                    'body': '<h1>Jason start</h1>'
                },
            },
        ]
    },
    '*_bar': {
        'name': "Ends with",
        'default_plugins': [
            {
                'plugin_type': 'TextPlugin',
                'values': {
                    'body': '<h1>Jason end</h1>'
                },
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It seems that this is currently not possible. Could you add a template tag or a include file, and add this before/after the placeholders location inside your Django templates?

Comment: There's no solution for this, I've tried different things. I have a multisite where the placeholder name changes according to the site.

Comment: You can name a placeholder using a context variable in the `.html` files, but in `settings.py` you need to specify your placeholder names.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no out-of-the-box solution, as `settings.py` is a python file, nothing is stopping you from dynamically generating CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF or enhancing it accordingly.

The challenge is that you still need to know all of the possible placeholders in advance.

Another (albeit less maintainable) solution would be to monkey-patch the `get_placeholder_conf` function in https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/0d25012fce3743130a4c94418c523faa568f2a76/cms/utils/placeholder.py#L40 - there you can do further processing based on the placeholder name.